Trouble displaying YOLOv8 classification results in React Native app using Flask API
I am developing a React Native mobile application that utilizes a Flask API for object detection and classification using the YOLOv8 model. The backend API successfully classifies images sent from the app, and I can see the correct classification results in the VS Code terminal.
However, when I test the API using Postman, I only receive a partial response or no visible classification results. The expected response should include JSON data with details about the classified objects, such as snake names, probabilities, and venom status.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
Flask API (app.py):
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from PIL import Image
from ultralytics import YOLO

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the YOLOv8 model
model_yolo = YOLO('models/best.pt')

@app.route('/classify', methods=['POST'])
def classify():
    if 'image' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No image found'})

    img_file = request.files['image']
    img = Image.open(img_file)

    # Run inference on the image using YOLOv8
    results = model_yolo.predict(img)
    formatted_predictions = get_snake_info(results)

    return jsonify({'predictions': formatted_predictions})

def get_snake_info(predictions):
    # Snake names and venom status lists
    snake_names = ["Common Indian Krait", "Green Vine Snake", "Hump Nosed Viper", "Indian Cobra", "Python", "Russells Viper"]
    venom_status = ["Highly-Venomous", "Non-Venomous", "Highly-Venomous", "Highly-Venomous", "Non-Venomous", "Highly-Venomous"]
    
    top_predictions = []
    for prediction in predictions:
        snake_name = prediction[0]
        if snake_name in snake_names:
            snake_index = snake_names.index(snake_name)
            venom = venom_status[snake_index]
            confidence = float(prediction[1])
            top_predictions.append({'snake_name': snake_name, 'probability': confidence, 'venom_status': venom})

    return top_predictions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)  # Run the Flask app



React Native Screen (ResultsScreen.js):
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const ResultsScreen = ({ route }) => {
    const { image } = route.params;
    const [results, setResults] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchResults = async () => {
            try {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', {
                    uri: image.uri,
                    type: 'image/jpeg',
                    name: 'image.jpg',
                });
                const response = await fetch('http://192.168.8.197:5000/classify', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                    body: formData,
                });
                const data = await response.json();
                setResults(data.predictions);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching results:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchResults();
    }, [image]);

    return (
        <View>
            {/* Display classification results */}
        </View>
    );
};

export default ResultsScreen;

I need assistance in understanding why Postman is not showing the complete classification results, even though the Flask API returns the correct data. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
